# how to get "billboard hot 100" chart listing via billboard API

Tags: json, api

I have been trying for hours on how to exactly get the "billboard hot 100" chart (The results matching to http://www.billboard.com/#/charts/hot-100)...
but have had no success till yet.

I have gone through the API documentation at http://developer.billboard.com/docs thoroughly...

And from what i understand from here -> developer.billboard.com/docs/read/The_Chart_Service/Resources/Chart_Spec
"billboard hot 100" has id "379"

But when i use it in chart item call, like this -> api.billboard.com/apisvc/chart/v1/list?id=379&format=json&api_key=bvk4re5h37dzvx87h7rf5dqz

i just get an error :(

if anyone has experience using the api please help me...

Thanks

Comment: Recently I have been trying the same thing. I think the billboard API is dead :(

Answer (score 12):

**Update 2020-01-21**

The RSS feed is now dead. You can view a historical snapshot of the feed at archive.org https://web.archive.org/web/2020*/http://www.billboard.com/rss/charts/hot-100.

However you will likely need to use web scraping to get the data now.

- NodeJS scraper: https://github.com/darthbatman/billboard-top-100

---

The Billboard API seems to dead now with no sign of anyone maintaining it.

However they do provide a rss feed for the Hot 100 see http://www.billboard.com/rss/charts/hot-100. You might be able to get the information you need from that.

Comment: It appears that this feed unfortunately no longer exists

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to know Python, check out [billboard.py](https://github.com/guoguo12/billboard-charts).

From the linked page:

```
pip install billboard.py
```

```
>>> import billboard
>>> chart = billboard.ChartData('hot-100')
>>> song = chart[0]  # Get no. 1 song on chart
>>> song.title
u'One Dance'
>>> song.artist
u'Drake Featuring WizKid & Kyla'
>>> song.weeks  # Number of weeks on chart
15
>>> song.spotifyID
u'11hqMWwX7sF3sOGdtijofF'
```

Comment: I just tried this module and it works. BUT, there's no spotifyID field. The fields are pretty limited - title, artist, weeks (and ranking implied by array position)

Answer (score 0):

According to an entry on ProgrammableWeb, the Billboard API was officially terminated in May 2013.

As Matthew Moisen suggested above, try the Python module billboard.py. I just tried it a few minutes ago. While it's limited in fields (and maybe charts), it does provide basic data for at least the top-100 chart.

Here is the github repo: https://github.com/guoguo12/billboard-charts